# When to keep a reference to a UITableView

Tags: iphone

This is probably a dumb question but I'm just learning.  If I have a method that creates a UITableView in code when a button is pressed like this

```
UITableViewcontroller *contentView = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithSytyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
contentView.tableView.delegate = self;
contentView.tableView.datasource = self;
[contentView release];
```

In the UITableView delegate and datasource methods, how do I check if it is this tableView or another TableView?  Do I have to have to have an instance variable for this tableView that always points to it for those delegate and datasource methods?  Thanks.

Comment: How many table views do you have in that ViewController?  Usually there is only one tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tag property. In your code

```
UITableViewcontroller *contentView = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithSytyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
contentView.tag == 10;//add this line in your code
contentView.tableView.delegate = self;
contentView.tableView.datasource = self;
[contentView release];
```

then in your delegate method or datasource methods check

```
if(view.tag == 10)
{
//do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you’d put the datasource and delegate methods in the table view, not the table view’s parent. That way you could separate the logic for each table view into its own view controller. But, if you must put them all in one class, you can use the `tag` property of the table view to keep track of which is which.